# Fatal mistake: Uninstalled sys-devel/binutils - emerge don't work anymore

Tags: gentoo, gcc, emerge

I cleaned up my system 3 weeks ago and made a fatal mistake. Well, I don't really know why, but I uninstalled **sys-devel/binutils**.

After I recognized the mistake I tried re-emerge, but it doesn't work.
Next step was downloading stage3 from Gentoo and copying `sys-devel/binutils` from there to local tree. 
Didn't work.

When I try to emerge something like `x11-apps/xinput`, I receive the following:

*output from emerge:*

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/tmp/portage/x11-apps/xinput-1.6.2/work/xinput-1.6.2_build':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

*config.log from emerge:*

```
configure:3372: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3394: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -m32 -march=core-avx-i -mtune=core-avx-i -O2 -pipe  -Wl, -O1 -Wl, --as-needed conftest.c  >&5
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction (program as)
```

*ldd from /usr/bin/as:*

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffee41b9000)
libopcodes-2.25.1.so => /usr/lib64/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/2.25.1/libopcodes-2.25.1.so (0x00007f2045ff8000)
libbfd-2.25.1.so => /usr/lib64/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/2.25.1/libbfd-2.25.1.so (0x00007f2045cd3000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2045abd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2045722000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f204551e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f204637f000)
```

*using:*

- sys-devel/binutils-2.25.1-r1
- sys-devel/gcc-4.9.3

---

**Any suggestions to do? Any hints? Any ideas to fix? Let me know!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying `sys-devel/binutils` didn't fix your problem because that is just the ebuild which defines the build and installation process for `binutils`.  It doesn't work because you need that package to build anything, as you've come to realize.  What you need to do instead is to copy the files that are part of that package.  The files and directories are:

```
/etc/env.d/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-2.25.1
/usr/lib64/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/*
/usr/share/binutils-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/*
/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/binutils-bin/*
```

Copy (recursively) these files/directories from the stage 3 tarball into your live system.  Afterwards, run `env-update` and either log out and back in or `source /etc/profile` to load the updated environment.  Check that things work and the first thing you should do after that is `emerge binutils` to build that package properly and record it in your world file.

If, after this, you still cannot emerge things, you may have to repeat the process with other packages.  As a worse case, you can copy the `/usr` and `/bin` hierarchy over from the stage 3 build and if you do that I'd recommend that be followed up with `emerge --sync` and `emerge -e world` to rebuild everything.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, casey is right. Short (but not quick) way is:

download current stage3 from https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/ - use correct stage3 for your architecture

unzip/untar it to /:

```
xz --decompress stage3-*.xz
tar -xvf stage3*.tar -C /
```

update environment:

```
env-update
source /etc/profile
```

emerge all again (this will take a lot of time)

```
emerge -avqeDN @world
```

reboot

```
reboot
```

I hope that it will help.